# Handlebars parse error on #each

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm returning the following JSON object

```
{"status":"success",
"valmessage":"Your message has been sent successfully.",
"postcontent":{
    "post_author":1,
    "post_recipient":"1",
    "post_title":"handle test 2",
    "post_type":"wp_inbox_msg",
    "post_content":"<p>giving it another go.<\/p>\n"},
"postmeta":{
    "postid":410,
    "postdate":"Monday, March 17th, 2014",
    "author":"admin"},"replies":null,
    "Formerrors":[]
}
```

and I'm getting the following error inside my handlebars template :

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 23:
...replies}}                    {{ #each replies }
----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

inside my tempalte I'm doing the following :

```
        {{#if replies}}
                {{ #each replies }}
                    <li>
                        <figure class="reply-author-img">
                            <img alt="" src="{{ avatar }}" height="96" width="96">
                        </figure>
                        <div class="replycontentwrap">
                            <div class="reply-from">
                                <p class="reply-author">
                                    <strong>{{ fullname }}</strong>
                                    <span>{{ nickname }}</span>
                                </p>
                                <span class="replydate">{{ reply_date }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="reply-content">{{ reply_content }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {{ /each }}
            {{/if}}
```

Replies is currently Null but it should be returning a set of objects when there are replies to the message, How would be the best way to 1) get this working and 2) approach this kind of data structure with handlebars.js ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error you are getting is a result of the fact that you have a space before the '#each' and '/each', so make it:

```
{{#each replies}}
    /* each stuff */
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Legend....  can't believe such a simple thing destroyed my whole template. This worked perfectly.

Comment: i can't believe this. Is this some kind of joke! do you know why this restriction?

Comment: Handlebars devs have to be playing jokes on us lol.

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly use as below to reduce complexity, also you get good understanding if there are multiple each blocks.

```
{{#replies}}
   {{this}}
{{/replies}}
```

This method is parallel to `#each` and can iterate key value if it is **object**, otherwise array index and object(value)

Comment: I suppose it makes sense that mustache syntax is also supported, but that is not really covered in the docs. Interesting ...